# New JFrame with TextArea

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a new JFrame that contains a TextArea in my Java Swing application. I've made the JFrame and assigned it to a button but making a TextArea inside the new window so to speak seems a bit more difficult that I imagined. My app looks like this so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaJa8.jpg

Here's my code:

```
public class UserInterface extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField brugernavn;

String username = "";
String password = "";   
private JPasswordField adgangskode;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UserInterface frame = new UserInterface();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

public UserInterface() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    brugernavn = new JTextField();
    brugernavn.setBounds(6, 41, 134, 28);
    contentPane.add(brugernavn);
    brugernavn.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblBrugernavn = new JLabel("Brugernavn");
    lblBrugernavn.setBounds(22, 20, 98, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblBrugernavn);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Adgangskode");
    label.setBounds(22, 88, 98, 16);
    contentPane.add(label);

    JButton btnFindMitSkema = new JButton("Find mit skema");
    btnFindMitSkema.setBounds(6, 175, 150, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnFindMitSkema);

    adgangskode = new JPasswordField();
    adgangskode.setBounds(6, 116, 134, 28);
    contentPane.add(adgangskode);

    JLabel titel = new JLabel("Skema-checker for Elevplan v1");
    titel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    titel.setBounds(151, 11, 298, 28);
    contentPane.add(titel);

    final JFrame LicensInfoFrame = new JFrame("Licens & info");

     final String GPL = "Elevplan checker version \n"
                + "Copyright (C) 2013  Philip Jakobsen \n"
                + "This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify \n"
                + "it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by \n"
                + "the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or \n"
                + "(at your option) any later version. \n"
                + "This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, \n"
                + "but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of \n"
                + "MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the \n"
                + "GNU General Public License for more details. \n"
                + "You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License \n"
                + "along with this program.  If not, see \n"
                + "http://www.gnu.org/licenses"; 

     final String licensinfoframeheader = "Licens & info";

    JButton btnLicensInfo = new JButton("Licens & info");
    btnLicensInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LicensInfoFrame.pack();
            LicensInfoFrame.setVisible(true);

            LicensInfoFrame.setTitle(licensinfoframeheader);

        }
    });
    btnLicensInfo.setBounds(6, 245, 150, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnLicensInfo);

    final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.setBounds(162, 41, 428, 233);
    contentPane.add(textArea);
    textArea.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    btnFindMitSkema.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            username = brugernavn.getText();
            password = adgangskode.getText();
            String output = "";
            new Backend();
            try {
                output = Backend.main(username, password);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            textArea.setText(output);

        }
    });



}
    }
```

In short, I want to add a TextArea to the JFrame that is triggered by the button labeled "License & info". The JFrame itself works fine but is empty.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific. I want to add a TextArea to my new JFrame that is triggered by the button labeled "License & info".

Answer (score 2):

You should add Text Area to JScrollPane.

Futhermore, I suggest to use Swing editors like default NetBeans Swing editor as these tools are making interface coding much easier and allow you to focus on what is most important.

Comment: They also have large over-heads, and the programmer doesn't learn anything about how the interface is put together.

Comment: I'm currently using WindowBuilder with Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `null` layout for any swing component. It would not only a nightmare for you to handle the GUI but also will posses problem to display across various platforms. You should let the inbuilt `Layouts` of Swing to take care of the GUI rendering. You should look at A [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to understand how to use the inbuilt layouts in Swing.
Also , never create more than one [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) in an application. To achieve such tasks you can use [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) or [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) or [`JInternalFrames`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html). What I suggest you that you start programming swing application from scratch . First understand the `Layouts` and how the GUI components work at [swing official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). After you get yourself in comfort zone , then create big applications consolidating your knowledge in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can [take a look](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m92x7qyi06e59hj/pZzM3qfI8L)
Further you can add a JTextArea to one of your panel make it to setVisible(false) by default and by using JButton actionListener take it back for your user as setVisible(true)